# Codeigniter Query is not working getting ERROR 500

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, http, http-status-code-500

I have developed codeigniter application before 1 year and it is hosted on cpanel.

It is working fine but past 4 days only one option alone is not working , I done debugging and found the issue with query.

In model page I have executed query like

```
$queryString = "select * 
               from tbl_order_request 
               left join tbl_brand on tbl_order_request.brand_id = tbl_brand.brand_id 
               left join tbl_category on tbl_order_request.category = tbl_category.category_id 
               where tbl_order_request.order_request_id='".$id."' 
               order by tbl_order_request.order_id";

$query3 = $this->db->query($queryString);

return $query3->result();
```

While executing this query itself I am getting page not working HTTP 500 error.

But application developed before 1 year. I didn't made any changes on this.

Comment: You should check for error logs on the server so you would have more details regarding the bug. Share the error log in your question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [This page isn’t working error in Codeigniter after executing query in model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47392378/this-page-isn-t-working-error-in-codeigniter-after-executing-query-in-model)

Comment: pls dude - don't post your questions twice, just because you didn't get an answer. Instead, edit your other question to improve it. Posting intentional duplicates is a violation of this site's behavior guidelines

Comment: i have deleted the previous post.

Comment: i have tried simple query inside that function.but it is also not working

Comment: $query = $this->db->query("select * from tbl_order_request");             print_r($query->result());

Answer (score 0):

Well first you need to load `dabatase` in `autoload.php`.

Secondly your query should be as per CodeIgniter Query Set.

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('tbl_order_request');
$this->db->join('tbl_brand', 'tbl_order_request.brand_id = tbl_brand.brand_id', 'left');
$this->db->Join('tbl_category', 'tbl_order_request.category = tbl_category.category_id', 'left');
$this->db->where('tbl_order_request.order_request_id', $id);
$this->db->order_by('tbl_order_request.order_id');
$query = $this->db->get();
$result= $query->result();
```

Comment: ok check log and share here. 
then definitely some field spelling issue